# Bulk API Hard Delete seems to be unavailable in our org

Tags: administration, profile, bulk-api

We have Enterprise addition and I've followed the following KB article and am unable to find this checkbox option anywhere. Has anyone else experienced this issue and is this something that needs to be enabled via Salesforce support? Please see below ref. KB. thanks.

**[Activation of Bulk API Hard Delete on System Administrator profile](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171306&language=en_US)**

Knowledge Article Number: 000171306

**Description**
I'd like to have the option 'Bulk API Hard Delete' activated for the system administrator profile. As an admin how can I set up myself with this permissions?

**Resolution**
1. Go to **Manage Users-->Profile**

1. Open the **‘System Administrator’** profile and hit the **‘Clone’** Button.
2. Enter a **suitable profile name** and **save** it.
3. **Edit the profile** which you saved at step 3.
4. Under **"Administrative permissions"**, check the **‘Bulk API Hard Delete’** checkbox.
5. **Save** it and assign this profile to the desired users.

Answer (score 2):

**Salesforce developer support had to enable the 'Bulk API' feature on our org.**
Once that was accomplished, I created a permission set and in the 'System Permissions' area I was able to find the check box for 'Bulk API' then I assigned myself to the permission set.

Thanks Salesforce.